# Vue.js with Google Auth using modules?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, vue.js, google-oauth

I'd like to use Vue.js together with the Google client library to authenticate with Javascript, but am having trouble finding a project which demonstrates this without relying on transpilers, bundlers or Node/npm. Is there such a thing in existence? I'm just trying to develop a small Vue app which interacts with Google APIs and don't want to over-complicate things.

For now, the only requirement is that it run in a recent version of Chrome which implements modules.

Comment: I just found the article titled "Goodbye webpack: Building Vue.js Applications Without webpack" at https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/goodbye-webpack-building-vue-applications-without-webpack/. It looks quite promising.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/authentication).

And [here is the vanilla-javascript sample page](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/samples/samples#authorizing-and-making-authorized-requests).

And with all due respect, then I must admit, that I would argue that it is to over-complicate it, by deciding not to use NPM or some package-system or something. Like saying: I want to build a house, but I don't want to over-complicate it using hammers and tools and stuff. ;-)

I think I would have looked into either [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-google-auth) or [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-google-oauth2), but I don't have experience with either, so I can't recommend it. And it breaks with the premise of your question.

Comment: If I can't do it from the command line, I have no use for it. I definitely can't do npm, etc without IDE magic. `npm install` routinely fails when following the README.md with popular packages. And I just read a great writeup by Google about module systems that says that engineers are working hard to obviate bundlers and provide a transparency that is sorely needed for debugging.

Comment: Here's that writeup on modules which I found highly encouraging: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/modules

Comment: None of the provided examples use modules.